# Facebook OpenGraph images are not loaded (in preview box only!)

Tags: wordpress, image, facebook, facebook-opengraph

For a month Facebook sharer does not show the featured image of any posts of my Wordpress sites in the sharer (preview) box. I am experienced with the sharer function and have been using it for 5 years without any problems.

Although I can't see the post's featured image in the preview box, it appears perfectly in the published post (on timeline).

Let's see an example of a post: [LINK #1](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/?q=https%3A%2F%2Ffodel.nl%2Fhu%2Fboerderij-te-koop-4189%2F) and [LINK #2](https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Ffodel.nl%2Fhu%2Fboerderij-te-koop-4189%2F)

- Notice that **there is no featured image** in the preview boxes, both cases.
- There is no error or warning messages at all just **Response Code 200**.
- The "Link Preview" text is shown correctly.
- The Image URL (og:image) is shown correctly **but the image won't load anyway**.
- The image URL is always correct. If I paste it into a browser it will load at once.
- There is no redirection that leads to a corruption. The site is the same for years.
- I can press the "Scrape again" button of course but to no avail.

[Screenshot of "Facebook for developers" page - No image in preview box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldluc.png)

[Screenshot of "Facebook sharer" page - No image in preview box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meeeW.png)

The situation is the same with all posts of 2 different sites. I wrote the same to Facebook support 3 weeks ago but they have not answered my question.

Only preview boxes are involved in the missing images problem. When I send the posts, images will load and show up flawlessly.

Please, if someone has any idea, send me an advice how the preview box could be fixed to show up the post's featured image in advance (before posting) too.

Thank you!

---

UPDATE: 20.08.2021.

After the publication of a post about the Facebook images are not loaded globally (in Hungary) by the leader Hungarian newsportal "Origo", Facebook fixed this serious error at once.

https://www.origo.hu/techbazis/20210819-fb-hiba.html

---

What is the lesson?

Never try to write to Facebook support because they don’t care of people at all. Submit your problem to a news portal and if it becomes a nationwide article, Facebook will respond. Otherwise, it may take up to a month for a substantive change to be made. This is the situation in Hungary.

As for the comments, thank you guys!

Comment: I have just tested with the link you shared, and it seems to share with a picture on Facebook for me. In my experience this can be caused by a slow connection to the server when Facebook caches the page/post. As far as hotlink protection this should not effect it as Facebook caches the results on their servers rather then directly linking back to your images. Once they cached it they will keep the cached version for a while, the scrape again button should normally force it to recache the page/post [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIqGJ.png)

Comment: Thank you Jasper for your answer. It is interesting that the picture has been loaded at your place.

Formerly I could erase the cache at once by pressing Scrape again. The difference:

When there is no image/text there is no 200 response code and no "Link Preview" text or recognized OG:Image tag at all. Everything is empty because it was cached previously the post was finalized.

So after publishing a post I always go to Facebook sharer page, check the preview and if it looks so that your screenshot than its OK. If not, I go to the developers page and do a cache reset, then recheck it.

Comment: It was working every time. Now the problem is I got a response code 200 with all the tags filled in (Text, image URL etc.) but the image will not show up. But only the image! The text is there. Very strange. 

And in this case "Scrape again" does simply nothing, however, it was also working formerly. Is it possible that only Hungarian FB site is involved by this weird malfunction? Hmmm.

This could explain that you got it working, while it does not reload the image here at my place (Hungary).

Comment: I've checked again the problem by publishing real posts on FB not just previewing them.

It is working. Posts on FB timeline do show the featured (opengraph) image of the post.

Only preview panes are dead here! Its the same I enter the link either in timeline posting box or on the "https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?..." page sharer box. They just won't show up.

How can I enter screenshots here in comments?

So FB cache has nothing to do with this problem, because nothing wrong is cached just the real image that is pretty good.

Comment: Now I reedit my original post.

Comment: `The situation is the same with all posts of 2 different sites. I wrote the same to Facebook support 3 weeks ago but they have not answered my question.`, they are notoriously bad in answering questions of paying customers, let alone when asking about something not related to paying them ;)

Comment: As for the issue at hand, could you try a speed test of the given page with for example [Pagespeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/). See if it is complaining about the server response time. I've had issues with this in the past causing it to not load the `og:image` at times

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm too that the image is loaded both in LINK #1 and LINK #2.
Maybe try with another browser or vpn?

Comment: Yes, thank you. It is working again because the problem I have described above has been fixed by Facebook.

And why just now after a month? Yesterday the Hungarian leader newsportal released an article about the some problems, so it was not my system (I tried VPNs before my post) and neither was the speed the cause.

https://www.origo.hu/techbazis/20210819-fb-hiba.html
Facebook read the leader tech news, feeled ashamed and fixed the issue at once.